# Change the ControlToValidate of RequiredFieldValidator dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, validation, requiredfieldvalidator

I have a textbox and dropdown inside a `<td>` based on certain condition I'll have to hide the text box and show the dropdown. If dropdown is visible is it possible to use the same requiredfield Validator. Is this possible?

```
<td>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtLimit" runat="server" />
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCurLiabiltyLimits" runat="server" CssClass="TextNormal" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCurLiabiltyLimits_SelectedIndexChanged">  
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtLimit" ErrorMessage="Answer is required." ClientIDMode="Static" />
</td>
```

In my code behind :

```
RequiredFieldValidator1.ControlToValidate = ddlCurLiabiltyLimits.ID ;
```

but this doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: When do you substitute `CintrolToValidate`?

Comment: After the page load and in the click event of Validate button.

Comment: What do you mean "after the page load"?  What validate button?

Comment: When I run into this pattern I always use a separate set of validator controls for each set of controls I might display.  Especially considering you are validating two different types of controls, it might be clearer to read if you have a validator for each control.  However what you propose is possible if done correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing that might be causing you problems is when using RequiredFieldValidator on a DropDownList, you will want to specify the RequiredFieldValidator.InitialValue property to indicate the Value of the "first" item in the DropDownList.  Maybe that is where your problem is?

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you might be assigning the ID to the ControlToValidate property too late in the page lifecycle.  Is it possible to assign this during the page's OnInit event?

It might be easier to just use a second RequiredFieldValidator for the DropDownList.

Comment: I tested this scenario out and setting RequiredFieldValidator.ControlToValidate in Page.Load works fine.

Comment: @pseudocoder - Ah, good to know.  Sounds like the OP is doing this inside of a Button's Click event, though.